# Ошибка Cannot find module в ts-node

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

Как исправить ошибку, вот что выдаёт консоль:

```
$ ts-node ./src/
Error: Cannot find module '@src/store/app-settings'
```

---

Думаю, что ошибка в том, что `ts-node` не может "пройтись" по пути с алиасами.

В документации сказано, что `ts-node` использует файл `tsconfig.json`, но у меня в нём прописаны алиасы, и они работают. TypeScript в IDE не ругается на них

---

Вот команда запуска `ts-node` в `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "ts": "ts-node ./src/"
 },
```

---

Мой конфиг в `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2020",

    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["*"],
      "@api/*": ["api/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["pages/*"],
      "@components": ["components"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@modals/*": ["components/modal/content/*"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": ["src/**/*", "declarations.d.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте изменить `baseUrl` на обычную строку без косой черты `"baseUrl": "src",`

Comment: Очень странная у вас конфигурация 

Comment: @Избытоксусликов та же ошибка. А почему странная?

Comment: И тут тоже `"src/**/*"`.

Comment: Ошибка не пропала

Comment: Странная потому что у "exclude" по умолчанию читает папку node_modules